# Using USB gamepad from Java app

Tags: java, usb, joystick, gamepad

Is there any way to use my generic usb gamepad from my java application?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the [nicegamepads](http://code.google.com/p/nicegamepads/) library.  It is a library which in turn builds upon the [Jinput](http://java.net/projects/jinput) library.

Answer (score 0):

I use Gamepad4j:- https://github.com/born2snipe/gamepad4j .  There is also JInput - https://jinput.github.io/jinput/.  Alternatively, jMonkeyEngine has support for Gamepads built in, as does LibGDX.  And there's also https://github.com/williamahartman/Jamepad/.